# Is there a way to open a file with a csv extension that has the file format of an XLS file, using python?

Tags: python, csv, format, xls, jsondecodeerror

I have a file with .csv extension with an XLS file format.
Whenever I want to read it via python (openpyxl or xlrd) it gives a UnidecodeError.
When I manually save the file as .csv than I can read it properly.
Is there a way to read it somehow without manually having to save it as .csv again?
When I use Matlab I can open it using XLSread without any problem, but I need it specifically for python.

Comment: check this: https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.read_excel.html

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.